# What exactly is ecriptfs? (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, root

My computer has been telling me "file system '/' has `200mb available."

I figured, after 5 years of constant downloading, my hard drive was full. So I go to the store and get another external hard drive to move everything onto. The problem hasn't changed at all. After having it analyzed, it says over 200gb of my hard drive is being taken up by my home directory. When looking further into that it's about 100gb from home and 100gb from ecriptfs. What is ecriptfs? Is it just encrypted copies of all my old files? Can I just wipe the entire thing and free up the space I need?

Comment: Install this software: `sudo apt-get install ncdu` and then run `sudo ncdu /`. This will give you a detailed output of your storage.

Answer (score 0):

> eCryptfs is a POSIX-compliant enterprise cryptographic stacked
>   filesystem for Linux. eCryptfs stores cryptographic metadata in the
>   header of each file, so that encrypted files can be copied between
>   hosts; the file will be decrypted with the proper key in the Linux
>   kernel keyring. There is no need to keep track of any additional
>   information aside from what is already in the encrypted file itself.
>   You may think of eCryptfs as a sort of "gnupg as a filesystem".
>
> eCryptfs is widely used, as the basis for Ubuntu's Encrypted Home
>   Directory, natively within Google's ChromeOS, and transparently
>   embedded in several network attached storage (NAS) devices.<sup>[eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/about.html)</sup>

More information can be found at [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html)